# Measuring veloctiy by detecting objects with an analog sensor

Tags: microcontroller, signal-processing

I have a sensor ([DRV425](http://www.ti.com/product/DRV425)) which outputs an analog voltage. The voltage level changes to a lower voltage when the sensor pass an object. Please take a look at the screenshot. It shows the output signal of the sensor after passing 6 objects.

[image]

The length of the spikes depend on the velocity of the sensor and I want to measure the time between each of this spikes to calculate the velocity of this sensor. My actual idea is to measure the voltage with an ADC and calculate the average of the signal. But this idea is not very robust against some noise or some kind of peaks in the output voltage. So I´m thinking about some better ideas.

- Does it make sense to use a moving average (exponential moving
  average) filter on this signal? As far as I know the exponential
  moving acts as a kind of low pass filter and so I don´t know if this
  works.
- Does it make sense to average the data points and check if the average changes to detect if the voltage is above a threshold. This can start a counter and I stop it when the voltage is under a threshold to measure the length of the peak? With this I can calculate the time, by knowing the sample rate of the ADC and with the width of the measured objects I can calculate the velocity.

Comment: The normal approach would be to use the microcontrollers analog comparator (built in to most 8/16 bit chips), one leg has an RC to represent the average voltage, the other is the input voltage with a bias to reduce false triggering

Comment: Do you have the name or datasheet for the sensor?

Comment: @PrateekDhanuka I have added it in my question.

Comment: @Reroute this was my very first idea, but I need some more sensors later and the microcontroller has only one AC.

Comment: Do the sensors have to be measured at the same time? as you can for most older AVR chips use the ADC mux to feed the analog comparator, The other approach is just do the same with external comparators feeding a pin each, and just capturing clock on the rising or falling edge.

Comment: @Reroute this sounds like a good idea. It´s not neccessary that all the sensor have to measure at the same time, so I can switch them and pass them to the AC.

Comment: @Reroute so you would pass the output voltage of the sensor through a RC (how you would design this RC?) and additionally you pass the output to the other input of the AC? Is this right or can you maybe show me some example schematic how you would do this.

Comment: You can probably (digitally) AC couple the signal and run it trough an integrator to return it to a square-ish waveform that is easier to measure time and polairty on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding to an answer,

The normal approach would be to use the microcontrollers analog comparator (built in to most 8/16 bit chips), one leg has an RC to represent the average voltage with a slight load to reduce the voltage on the RC by a little, so the signal needs to fall a certain amount before triggering, the other is the input possibly through the ADC mux for the older AVR style microcontrollers

Example circuit: [Falstad Circuit Simulator Link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+43%0Aa+176+176+288+176+9+5+0+1000000+2.4999999999999996+2.409812544560376+100000%0Ar+-16+160+64+160+0+1000%0Ac+64+160+64+224+0+0.00001+2.409812544560376%0Ag+64+224+64+240+0%0AR+-16+160+-112+160+4+5+40+-0.5+2.5+0+0.2%0Aw+-16+160+-16+288+0%0Aw+176+304+176+192+0%0AM+288+176+352+176+0+2.5%0A403+-176+208+-48+272+0+4_64_0_12546_2.5_0.0001_0_2_4_3%0Ar+128+224+128+160+0+100000%0Aw+176+160+128+160+0%0Aw+128+160+64+160+0%0Aw+64+224+128+224+0%0Ax+137+150+190+153+4+24+AIN0%0A160+176+304+112+304+0+20+10000000000%0Aw+-16+288+112+288+0%0Aw+112+320+-16+320+0%0AR+-16+320+-112+320+4+5+40+-0.5+2.5+0+0.2%0AL+144+320+144+368+0+0+false+5+0%0Ax+154+333+256+336+4+24+ADC%5CsMux%0Ao+7+64+0+4098+10+0.1+0+1%0A)[image]

This is relying on the assumtion your sensors are fairly well matched to one another, if they are not, you would either need a dedicated external comparator per input, or an analog switch to move the input to AIN0's RC network as you switch ADC mux inputs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But one last question..
Why you connect the output of the RC with the positive input of the AC? Wouldn´t it be a better solution if you connect the output of the RC with the negative input, so the AC will substract the DC part of the voltage from the input signal?

Comment: For most AVR microcontrollers, only the negative input of the comparator connects to the ADC mux, so had to work it that way, the timer capture doesn't care whether it is high or low, only that a change has occurred.

Comment: https://microchipdeveloper.com/8avr:analog-comparator-voltage-reference-overview for a more visual way of explaining the ADC multiplexer and how its used. I would imagine you would use the T1 Capture function, this stores the timer value when it changed high or low, from this you can read it, wait for the next update and use the 2 for your time difference.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it make sense to use a moving average (exponential moving average) filter on this signal? As far as I know the exponential moving acts as a kind of low pass filter and so I don´t know if this works.

Yes. But not as a low pass. As a high-pass to remove the DC offset.
This you can then put trough an integrator, since the signal looks like it is AC coupled.
After the integrator you will have something that resembles a square wave.

With that you can simply count the number of samples it is high/low and you know the time.
This way should be less susceptible to external fields or change of dc offset.

Perhaps you can trial this with your scope first. Set the channel AC coupled, and store the waveform data to a file for processing, in scilab for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to measure the period between triggered instances of multiple analog sensors, and you do not need to record the amplitude of the signal, but rather, just it's transition, then I would OR the signals using a [Schmitt Trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger) solution, moving your input signal from the analog domain into the digital domain.  The output of the Schmitt Trigger could then, of course, be interfaced to any digital input pin of your micro controller.